# How to analyze multiple choice data with logistic regression?

Tags: r, logistic, lme4-nlme, biostatistics

I have doubts about which is the best way of performing an analysis. It is the first time that I face this type of data.

Briefly, I am investigating if a number of variables are associated with the choice of a nest box. For this, I have data from 100 birds. These data consist of different nest boxes that have been visited by each of the birds. From this bunch of nest boxes, each bird ends up choosing 1. My aim is to explore if some variables may be influencing this choice.

For this, I coded a binary response variable for each of the nest boxes: chosen (y=1) or not (y=0) and built a model with the explanatory variable of interest. However, I don't know if this is correct as the number of not chosen boxes outnumbers the number of chosen boxes (the limit is 100, the same number of individuals).

So, the approach that I have taken is to build a dataset containing the 100 chosen nest boxes by each of the birds and 100 not chosen nest boxes picked up randomly from the set of boxes that were not chosen by each bird. Then conduct the logistic regression analysis and repeat the process 1000 times, to get average estimators. But I am not sure if this is correct. I struggle to find information on the internet because I don't know if this type of analysis has a specific name.

Any help will be so much appreciated

Comment: Have you considered multinomial logistic regression, which is specifically designed for this case?

Comment: Hi Noah. I am not quite sure about that since my dependent variable only has two outcomes: be or not chosen